# Taking apart a Function Expression - Struggling with a Couple Lines/Parameters

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, call

So I'm looking at a piece of code that is confusing me despite reading an explanation or two:

Here's the code..

```
var puzzlers = [
  function (a) { return 8*a - 10; },
  function (a) { return (a-3) * (a-3) * (a-3); },
  function (a) { return a * a + 4; },
  function (a) { return a % 5; }
];

var start = 2;

var applyAndEmpty = function (input, queue) {
  var length = queue.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    input = queue.shift()(input);
  }
  return input;
};

alert(applyAndEmpty(start, puzzlers));
```

I understand most of it but **a breakdown would be great**, what really boggles me is the beginning and end of this line `input = queue.shift()(input);` **I know it's using input to store the outcome, but why?** and **why is there an input parameter on the end** as well?

PS This line `alert(applyAndEmpty(start, puzzlers));` I know calls the function then alerts it. Why do I have to call a function before I can alert/console log etc it? Is this because it isn't IIFE and so theres nothing to actually alert until the function has been called? Its quite like an 'on' button?

Sorry this is long, thanks in advance!

Comment: `queue` is an array, and `shift` returns the first item in that array, which happens to be a function, and functions are called with `(arguments)`

Comment: Functions don't do anything until they're called. An IIFE calls the function immediately, but named functions are generally defined once so they can be called repeatedly with different inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've slightly edited the code in the `for` loop for clarity.

```js
// This array contains 5 items, each item is a function which takes a single param and returns a number.
var puzzlers = [
  function (a) { return 8*a - 10; },
  function (a) { return (a-3) * (a-3) * (a-3); },
  function (a) { return a * a + 4; },
  function (a) { return a % 5; }
];

// The start value is 2.
var start = 2;

var applyAndEmpty = function (input, queue) {
  // Get the number of items in the queue.
  var length = queue.length;
  // Iterate over all the items in the queue.
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    // Remove the item at index 0 from the queue, the item is stored in the var.
    var itemMethod = queue.shift();
    // Execute the method, pass it the current value as input param. The result 
    // of the method will be placed back into the input variable.
    input = itemMethod(input);
  }
  // Return the modified input value.
  return input;
};

// Runs the applyAndEmpty method and shows the output in an alert.
alert(applyAndEmpty(start, puzzlers));

// The breakdown of the for loop:
// i = 0, input = 2 -> return 8 * 2 - 10 = 6
// i = 1, input = 6 -> return (6-3) * (6-3) * (6-3) = 27
// i = 2, input = 27 -> return 27 * 27 + 4 = 733
// i = 3, input = 733 -> return 733 % 5 = 3
// And thus the alert says three.
```

If you don't place the result of the current `itemMethod` back into `input` it means you will call each method from `puzzlers` with the value `2`. The result of `applyAndEmpty` would no longer be 3 but just be 2 as the input variable is never changed. So if you don't store the result of calling the puzzler methods you might as well skip them altogether and just return the input param immediately.

Comment: Hey Thijs, thanks for the reply, great breakdown! I just wondered now, how does the `for` loop know it's running on the queue and not input? @Thijs

Comment: You're welcome! Can you rephrase your question? I am not sure what it is you want to know.

Comment: `// Iterate over all the items in the queue.
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {`  ............During this section of the script, how does the for loop know to iterate the queue parameter and not the input? Hope this made more sense >.<

Comment: The for loop doesn't "run on" anything. In the line above the code you pasted, the number of items in `puzzlers` is determined. The for loop will just do as many iterations as there are items in the `puzzlers` array. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a way to chain the functions in the array, so that the result from the first function is passed to the second function, the result from the second function is passed to the third function, and so on...

```js
f = [ a => 8 * a - 10,
      a => (a-3) * (a-3) * (a-3),
      a => a * a + 4,
      a => a % 5 ]

console.log(f[3](f[2](f[1](f[0](2)))))                // 3

console.log(f.pop()(f.pop()(f.pop()(f.pop()(2)))))    // 3

console.log((a => a % 5)((a => a * a + 4)((a => (a-3) * (a-3) * (a-3))((a => 8*a - 10)(2)))))   // 3
```